# If $a,b$ have order $2^j$ mod $p$, then $a\cdot b$ has order $2^{j'}$ mod $p$ for some $j'<j$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $p$ prime such that $(a,p)=(b,p)=1$. If $a,b$ have order $2^j$ mod $p$, then $a\cdot b$ has order $2^{j'}$ mod $p$ for some $j'<j$.

I have been trying this problem using that $ord_p(ab)\mid 2^j$. But I'm not sure.

Comment: If $a,b$ have order $2^j\bmod p$, then $a^{2^j}\equiv b^{2^j}\equiv1\bmod p$, so $(ab)^{2^j}\equiv1\bmod p,$  so $ord_p(ab)|2^j$, so $ord_p(ab)=2^{j'} $ for some $j'\mathbf \le j$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It simply suffices to show that $(ab)^m \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ where $m=2^{j-1}$. We know that $(a^m)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ but $a^m \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. This means that $a^m \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$. Similarly, $b^m \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$. Hence:
$$(ab)^m \equiv -1 \cdot -1 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
which proves the required.

Comment: Thank you, I liked your idea to prove the result.